# Knockout dynamic foreach

Tags: dynamic, foreach, knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout so forgive me.
Lets say I have two variables each containing an enumerable list of strings.
var oneStar= "a,b,c"
var twoStar= "d,e,f"

On the MVC view I have a two radio buttons that sets the observed model property "CoverLevel"

I then have a foreach that i want to make dynamic based on the selection of the radio button.

At the moment i'm doing this , but i know it's not semantically or otherwise correct.

```
<ul>
 <span data-bind="visible:  CoverLevel() == 21">
                            @foreach (string usp in oneStar)
                            {
                            <li>
                                <span class='usp-icon'></span>
                                <span class='usp-text'>@usp</span>
                            </li>
                        }
                            </span>
                            <span data-bind="visible:  CoverLevel() == 22>
                                @foreach (string usp in twoStar)
                                {
                                <li>
                                    <span class='usp-icon'></span>
                                    <span class='usp-text'>@usp</span>
                                </li>
                            }
                                </span> 
</ul>
```

How can i make the oneStar/twoStar list dynamic in the foreach loop based on the value of coverlevel please?

Many thanks Nick.

I've got a working solution but it isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

`Knockoutjs` uses the `checked` binding for `radio` button and `check` boxes.  A `computed` observable can be used to express 'a,b,c' as separate array elements. HTML example:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="flong" value="21" data-bind="checked: coverLevel">21</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="flong" value="22" data-bind="checked: coverLevel">22</label>
<ul data-bind="visible:  coverLevel() == 21,  foreach: oneStar">
  <li>
    <span class='usp-icon' data-bind="text: $data"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul data-bind="visible:  coverLevel() == 22,  foreach: twoStar">
  <li>
    <span class='usp-icon' data-bind="text: $data"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript model class:

```
class ModelModel {
  constructor() {
    this.coverLevel = ko.observable("21");
    this.oneStarString = ko.observable('a,b,c');
    this.oneStar = ko.computed(() => this.oneStarString().split(','));
    this.twoStarString = ko.observable('d,e,f');
    this.twoStar = ko.computed(() => this.twoStarString().split(','));
  }
}
const model = new ModelModel();

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  ko.applyBindings(model);
});
```

See working example at: https://jsfiddle.net/martlark/rx3se2m7/22/